# Node.js: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am setuping the MERN stack project, which was created by another developer and I am getting the error:

```
node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:82
[0]   if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
[0]                            ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
```

If I understand correctly, there should be clientID in .env file and there's no such file in the project, right?

Comment: A couple of questions for you: 1) what is the passport strategy you are using? Is it perhaps `passport-linkedin-oauth2` or else? 2) did you set the clientID inside the passport strategy, as for the clientID from the oauth2's provider? Share some code to reproduce the error

Comment: I have the same error did you manage to solve it

Comment: @Ahmed check my answer

Answer (score 3):

For me, I did something like this

```
passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy(
        {
            clientID: config.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            clientSecret: config.FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_SECRET,
            callbackURL: config.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL,
            profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email']
        },
```

But I forgot to add my `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` in my config file. Just make sure that your clientId being passed is not null or undefined

Answer (score 1):

> Be sure to npm install dotenv, and add require('dotenv').config(); to the top of your app.js file.

While the answer from @ColsonRice wasn't exactly the reason I received the above error `OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option`, it did point me in the right direction. In trying to get my Typescript version of my NodeJs express server working on Heroku I had changed (10 commits back), my package.json start script from

```
"start": "node -r dotenv/config ./dist/index.js",
```

to

```
"start": "node dist/index.js",
```

Change the development start up to use an alternative start command with the dotenv/config option back in resolved my issue. The last 4 lines of my scripts section of package.json are as follows:

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec npm run restart",
"restart": "rimraf dist && npm run build && npm run devstart",
"devstart": "node -r dotenv/config ./dist/index.js",
"start": "node dist/index.js",
```

So for me, the negative score for Colson is unjustified as it indirectly helped me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to npm install dotenv, and add require('dotenv').config(); to the top of your app.js file.

Comment: Your answer could be significantly improved if you added a few more details around your solution. Also you could explain what caused the error exactly - the poster does not seem to be very sure about it.

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is **config.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID** instead of **config.FACEBOOK_APP_ID**

**Error Strategy:**

```
passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy(
        {
            clientID: config.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: config.FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_SECRET,
            callbackURL: config.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL,
            profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email']
        },
```

**Correct Strategy:**

```
passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy(
        {
            clientID: config.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            clientSecret: config.FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_SECRET,
            callbackURL: config.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL,
            profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'email']
        },
```