# Heroku deployment

Tags: web, heroku, deployment

I was getting an error while deploying my website on heroku: 
cannot find module 'dotenv', then I looked around and found a solution:

```
if (app.get('env') == 'development') { require('dotenv').config(); }
```

then I got a new error stating:

```
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a ClientID option. <br>
```

It is working fine on localhost but throws an error when I try to deploy my app on heroku.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271428/node-js-oauth2strategy-requires-a-clientid-option)

Comment: nope. it didn't help